# How to update a DataTable created on Main Thread by a new thread in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have a global DataTable named 'DTImageList' and an XtraGrid named 'uxImageGrid'. Now there is a Method named 'prcFillImagesVideosAndFiles' in which we bring image data from data base page wise i.e. say 500 rows at a time and we create mannual Pages on top of the Grid by using XtraTabControl depending on the total count of data exists according to search. Say if we get 700 Images then will load only 500 at a time and 2 pages will be created as 'Page 1', 'Page 2'.
        But in 'prcFillImagesVideosAndFiles' method, we are not fetching the actual images but only its name, id etc. After this I created a new Thread and invoking a method runner which in turn calls a new method called 'FillImages' in which I look through DTImageList and bring actual image one by one from backend and update row with this image due to which XtraGrid starts showing images one by one.
        This process works fine for few minutes i.e. loads 20-25 images and after that it gives 'Cross-thread operation not valid' error.

// My prcFillImagesVideosAndFiles method's Code is:

```
`if (DTImageList != null)
                {
                    DTImageList.Rows.Clear(); DTImageList.Columns.Clear(); DTImageList = null;
                }

                string sql = @"select " + top + @" IM.Image_ID,IM.extension,IM.Is_Uploaded,cast(0 as varbinary) 'ActualImage',IM.description 'Description',IM.ContentType,IM.DateTime_Uploaded,IM.FolderName, '' as FilePath 
                           from images as IM where IM.GCRecord is null and IM.Is_Uploaded=1 " + MainCriteria + @" " + Ob + @"";

                string sql1 = LayoutPaging(sql);
                DTImageList = new DataTable();
                DTImageList = FillDataTable(sql1);
                DataTable DTdeliv2 = new DataTable();
                DTdeliv2.Columns.Add("Image");
                DTdeliv2.Columns.Add("UniqueNumber");
                DTdeliv2.Columns["Image"].DataType = typeof(Image);
                DTdeliv2.Columns["UniqueNumber"].DataType = typeof(int);
                DTImageList.Merge(DTdeliv2, true, MissingSchemaAction.Add);

                uxImageGrid.DataSource = null;
                uxImageGrid.DataSource = DTImageList;

                RepositoryItemTextEdit riTextEdit = new RepositoryItemTextEdit();
                riTextEdit.Appearance.TextOptions.HAlignment = HorzAlignment.Center;
                layoutView1.Columns["Description"].AppearanceCell.TextOptions.HAlignment = HorzAlignment.Center;

                riTextEdit.Appearance.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(255)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))), ((int)(((byte)(128)))));
                riTextEdit.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = true;
                riTextEdit.NullText = "";
                uxImageGrid.RepositoryItems.Add(riTextEdit);
                layoutView1.Columns["Description"].ColumnEdit = riTextEdit;
                riTextEdit.Leave += new EventHandler(riTextEdit_Leave);
                riTextEdit.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(riTextEdit_KeyPress);

                RepositoryItemPictureEdit riPictureEdit = new RepositoryItemPictureEdit();

                riPictureEdit.SizeMode = PictureSizeMode.Zoom;
                riPictureEdit.ShowMenu = false;
                riPictureEdit.NullText = "        Loading Image";
                riPictureEdit.Appearance.Image = Pionero.RetailTherapy.Properties.Resources.mag;


                uxImageGrid.RepositoryItems.Add(riPictureEdit);
                layoutView1.Columns["Image"].ColumnEdit = riPictureEdit;

                riPictureEdit.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(riPictureEdit_MouseMove);
                riPictureEdit.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(riPictureEdit_MouseDown);

                layoutView1.Columns["Image"].Caption = "";

                int k = DTImageList.Rows.Count;
                if (k > 0)
                {
                    DevExpress.Data.Filtering.CriteriaOperator expr1 = new DevExpress.Data.Filtering.BinaryOperator("Is_Uploaded", true);
                    layoutView1.ActiveFilterCriteria = expr1;
                    if (pthread != null)
                    {
                        StopRunningThread();
                    }
                    if (pthread == null || pthread.IsAlive==false)
                    {
                        pthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(runner));
                        pthread.IsBackground = true;
                        Is_ThreadNeededtoWork = true;
                        pthread.Start();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        Is_ThreadNeededtoWork = true;
                        pthread.Start();
                    }

                }`
```

//The runner method is:

```
 void runner()
    {
        if (Is_ThreadNeededtoWork == false)
        {
            if (dtImages != null)
            {
                dtImages.Rows.Clear(); dtImages.Columns.Clear(); dtImages = null;
            }
            return;
        }
            if (Is_ThreadNeededtoWork == true)
            {
                FillImages();
            }
    }
```

// FillImages method's code is:

```
try
        {
            if (DTImageList.Rows.Count <= 0) return;
            StringBuilder sbImagesNotLoaded = new StringBuilder();
            sbImagesNotLoaded.Append("Following images not loaded due to connection: ");
            ArrayList lstImage_IDs = new ArrayList();
            int NoOfAttempts = 0;

            //if (dtImages != null)
            //{
                for (int i = 0; i < DTImageList.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    NoOfAttempts = 0;
                V:
                    string Qry = @" Select Image_ID,image from images where Image_ID = " + DTImageList.Rows[i]["Image_ID"].ToString();
                    dtImages = FillDataTable(Qry);

                    if (dtImages != null && dtImages.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        if (DTImageList.Rows[i]["image"] == DBNull.Value)
                        {
                           // Thread.Sleep(100);
                            byte[] barr = (byte[])dtImages.Rows[0]["image"];
                            Image img = Global.byteArrayToImage(barr);
                            DTImageList.Rows[i]["Image"] = img;
                            DTImageList.AcceptChanges();
                            uxImageGrid.RefreshDataSource();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       // Thread.Sleep(100);
                        if (Convert.ToInt32(DTImageList.Rows[i]["Image_ID"]) > 0)
                            if (NoOfAttempts < 3)
                            {
                                NoOfAttempts = NoOfAttempts + 1;
                                goto V;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (lstImage_IDs.Count > 0)
                                    sbImagesNotLoaded.Append("," + Convert.ToString(DTImageList.Rows[i]["Description"]));
                                else
                                    sbImagesNotLoaded.Append(Convert.ToString(DTImageList.Rows[i]["Description"]));

                                lstImage_IDs.Add(DTImageList.Rows[i]["Image_ID"]);

                            }
                    }

                }



            //}

            if (lstImage_IDs.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < lstImage_IDs.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow drImage = DTImageList.Select("Image_ID=" + Convert.ToString(lstImage_IDs[i]) + "").FirstOrDefault();
                    if (drImage != null)
                        DTImageList.Rows.Remove(drImage);
                }
                DTImageList.AcceptChanges();

                XtraMessageBox.Show(sbImagesNotLoaded.ToString(), Global.Header, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

            EnableDisablePanelControls(true);
            if (pthread != null)
            {
                Is_ThreadNeededtoWork = false;
                StopRunningThread();
            }

        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException abortException)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception emmp)
        {
            EnableDisablePanelControls(true);
            //pthread.Abort();

        }
        finally
        {
            //Global.StopProg();
        }
```

//StopRunningThread() 's code is:

```
 void StopRunningThread()
    {
        if (dtImages != null)
        {
            dtImages.Rows.Clear(); dtImages.Columns.Clear(); dtImages = null;
        }

        Is_ThreadNeededtoWork = false;

    }
```

Thanks
Vicky

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Actually the main issue is: while pthread is executing fillImages method in which it loops through DTImageList dataTable, User changes the DTImageList dataTable completely by clicking on other Page. At this time i am getting issue of Cross Thread error as DTImageList changed by Main Thread while pthread was working on it. Please give me a proper solution for it.

Comment: To get a proper solution, you should ask a proper question. It is unreadable in this format, filled with unnecessary details.

Comment: Hi @14V, Sir if you read my texts carefully, the problem is stated very well. Anyway if the code is not readable then please read this: I have a problem: There is a dataTable which is global on a user control say DTImages which fills dynamically when user changes criteria on that control. Now as you know Images are very heavy to load so to make loading faster, I always bringing an Image column as blank in that dataTable. This datatable is assigned as datasource to an XtraGrid.

Comment: Now, I am loading images one by one by another thread. But the problem is while that thread is bringing images one by one. User is changing the search due to which the dataTable Re-fills with new data and at this time I need to stop that previous running thread and start working on this new updated rows. But while am doing this getting that Cross Thread Error. If you examine the code carefully. You will surely get the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try inserting images before you pass it as Datasource to uxImageGrid.
Add image column to DTImageLis.
     DTImageList.Columns.Add("Image", typeof(System.Drawing.Image));

Add the image to datatable based on Name,Id etc and bind it to uxImageGrid
     uxImageGrid.Datasource=DTImageList;